# PySpark - Convert python datastructure to RDD on executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark to parallelize some existing code that performs some data extraction and returns a pandas dataframe. I would like to convert these pandas dataframes to either one or many Spark dataframes.

Nb. the existing code is quite complex (involving calling native libraries etc), so porting this directly to Spark code is not an option.

Here's a simplified example of the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

def extract_df(s):
    # Lots of existing code that returns a large pandas dataframe
    # ...
    return pd.DataFrame({'x': s, 'y': [1, 2, 3], 'z': [4, 5, 6]})

sRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['A', 'B', 'C'])
dfsRDD = sRDD.map(lambda s: extract_df(s))
```

I know I can convert datesRDD to a Spark dataframe by collecting on the driver.

```
spark.createDataFrame(pd.concat(rdd.collect(), ignore_index=True)).show()
```

but that of course requires that I can hold the entire collection of Pandas dataframes in memory, which I can't.

At the moment, I'm writing the Pandas dataframes to json on S3, then reading using Spark, but that's using a *lot* of storage.

Is there some way that I can tell Spark to convert to an DataFrame/RDD on the executor itself? Or is there another approach that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Nice, flatMap to the rescue!

```py
import pandas as pd

def extract_df(s):
    # Lots of existing code that returns a **huge** pandas dataframe
    # ...
    df =  pd.DataFrame({'x': s, 'y': [1, 2, 3], 'z': [4, 5, 6]})
    return df.values.tolist()

datesRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['A', 'B', 'C'])

dfsRDD = datesRDD.flatMap(lambda s: extract_df(s))

spark.createDataFrame(dfsRDD, schema=['x', 'y', 'z']).show()

+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  4|
|  A|  2|  5|
|  A|  3|  6|
|  B|  1|  4|
|  B|  2|  5|
|  B|  3|  6|
|  C|  1|  4|
|  C|  2|  5|
|  C|  3|  6|
+---+---+---+
```